# Unable to get cart item when FPC is enabled Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, checkout, quoteitem

I'm trying to get all cart items in a custom block but unable to get all items, it's throwing an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAllItems()
>   on null in

Block Code:

```
<?php

namespace Arunendra\Mixin\Block\Cart;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $_session;
    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
    ) {
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }


    public function getProductIds()
    {
         $ids = $this->getData('_cart_product_ids');
        if ($ids === null) {
            $ids = [];
            foreach ($this->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $product = $item->getProduct();
                if ($product) {
                    $ids[] = $product->getId();
                }
            }
            $this->setData('_cart_product_ids', $ids);
        }
        return $ids;
    }
    public function getQuote()
    {
        return $this->_session->getQuote();
    } 

}
```

Comment: Did you tried with getAllVisibleItems()?

Comment: @RohanHapani Yes, got same error

Comment: It's magento default issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's bad solution. But, you need to set `cacheable="false"` in your block from layout file. Like this below way :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="RH\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld" cacheable="false" name="formbuilder" template="RH_Helloworld::helloworld.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

**One more way :**

You can set **$_isScopePrivate = true** If content of your block is user specific.

After that, you don't need to set **cacheable="false"** in your layout xml file.

I tested after set **$this->_isScopePrivate = true;** in my block's construct and it's return all quote items proper without **cacheable="false"**.

> _isScopePrivate is rendering private (session related) information on a cacheable page

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: How cross sell (Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell) working with cache enabled  ?

Comment: You get perfect output now? using isScopePrivate? @Arunendra